# GFI turns off dishwasher heating element

Tags: wiring, dishwasher

Kenmore Elite dishwasher doesn’t seem to be heating for dry cycle when used.

when taken apart heating element heats fine but GFI turns off.

What suggestion do you have to solve the problem?

Thanks for taking my inquiry.

Comment: sounds like a bad element with an internal short to ground.

Comment: do you mean GFCI?

Comment: I agree with Jason The heat rods do get cracks in them and a small leakage to ground will trip a GFI /GFCI and the heater may appear to function normally as time goes on it gets worse and then arcs from the center to the outer shield that’s when you can tell where the leakage was because now there is a hole usually.

Comment: so it only heats when isolated from the DW circuit?  when it's taken apart do you test it separately?

Comment: I may be slightly foggy , but aren't DW supposed to be on their own breaker? 15Amp? Is that correct?

Comment: @ojait the year built and jurisdiction would need to be known for GFCI for example 210.8.C was not adopted by my state and a dedicated circuit is not specifically required. At least in the 17 code. Many places suggest a 15 amp circuit.